# How do we get ALM Folder ID from IDE?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I am trying to upload test cases in ALM using paf, How do we get ALM Folder ID while executing scripts in eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 0):

ALM folder ID can be captured from IDE.

1. To get the ALM folder ID, click on the dropdown next to the Run
   button on the IDE and select “Run Configurations…”
2. On the “Run Configurations” window, select “Get Folder Id” → Select
   tab “Arguments” → Enter the Folder name.
3. Click on “Run” button and the ALM folder ID will be captured and
   displayed in the console tab.